# htaccess rewriterule with multi-directory string in parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have googled for a while now, but can't seem to find a solution, so I'll tailor a question directly to my problem.

I am working on a football/soccer website, and entered all the matches. Each database row has a field with a virtual filename in it, like "2010-season/26-may-2010/hometeam-vs-awayteam.php"

I want       --> /matches.php?url=2010-season/26-may-2010/hometeam-vs-awayteam.php 
to look like --> /matches/2010-season/26-may-2010/hometeam-vs-awayteam.php

My first guess was that the rewriterule would look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/matches/(.*)$ /matches.php?url=$1 [L]
```

But that only gives me a 404 error. I tried different approaches, but nothing solved my issue.
Is the problem that multiple subfolders are passed on into a single parameter?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /matches\.php\?url=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /matches/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^matches/(.*)$ /matches.php?url=$1 [L]
```

It will redirect `/matches.php?url=2010-season/26-may-2010/hometeam-vs-awayteam.php` to `/matches/2010-season/26-may-2010/hometeam-vs-awayteam.php` and then silently rewrite it back to `/matches.php?url=2010-season/26-may-2010/hometeam-vs-awayteam.php`.
In the `matches.php` file use `$_GET['url'];` to get the `url` parameter.

Comment: For some reason that didn't do the trick. The match.php file is in the same directory as the htaccess file. If I add an empty "matches" folder, then I get a 404 for matches.php, if I delete the folder "matches", then I get a 404 for the entire URL. And yes, matches.php has called the url via $_GET since the beginning. But something in the rewrite doesn't work.

Comment: Is the matches.php file in the root directory or is it in a subfolder e.g. http://example.com/somefolder/matches.php

Comment: Both. I ran it on a test domain (e.g. workshopdomain.com/test/soccer/matches.php) and a real domain (e.g. realdomain.com/matches.php). In both cases I have a htaccess in the same directory as the matches.php. Same result...404